# How to shorten file path (get canonical path) in java?

Tags: java, file, path

Is there any way in java which can shorten absolute path to directory.

For example:

`./data/../system/bin/` => `./system/bin/`

Comment: In what way would this be shortening? ./data is something totally different to ./system. The only way to shorten a ABSOLUTE path is to change its structure on the file system

Comment: notice the double dots
/data/.. leads to /

Comment: @user1902288 If I have to print path for some reason, I would like print shortest on (`./system/bin/`)

Comment: My missunderstanding, sorry ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath().

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/../Users");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()); // C:\Users\..\Users
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath()); // C:\Users
```

Comment: @bugybunny Thank you! All I needed :) @Trengot I check if file exists with `if(new File(path).exists()){}`

Comment: Yes it does work. An `IoException` is only throws if the path contains '\u0000'